# getStorageEncryptionStatus() on Android 8.0+

Tags: android, encryption, filesystems

We are developing a device admin app on Android, which needs to check the device encryption status. We are using the method `getStorageEncryptionStatus()` of `DevicePolicyManager` and it works fine on most of the devices.

However, on some (issue found on a Samsung Galaxy S8 with Android 8.0.0) the method returns `ENCRYPTION_STATUS_ACTIVE_DEFAULT_KEY` even if a password is set on the device. Some users experience the same issue, still with Samsung devices, is there anything that disallows to use that method with this manufacturer?

Comment: Just guessing here: maybe it uses a staggered setup where the encryption key is protected by Samsung, and the Samsung security (Knox?) is taking the password.

Comment: PS you can use backticks \` to indicate inline code, see the edit for details.